# swiftmailer spool file path

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I am trying to spool emails and I am confused when it comes to `swiftmailer` spool file path, I am not sure where to get a path ? if someone could point me in the right direction, thanks in advance !

because I when I try to run this command ,

```
php app/console swiftmailer:spool:clear-failures --env=prod
```

it gives me this error

```
"The parameter "swiftmailer.spool.file.path" must be defined"
```

//what to do put for the path here

```
$spoolPath = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('swiftmailer.spool.file.path');
```

do I call it here ?

```
 # app/config/config.yml
swiftmailer:
    # ...
    spool:
        type: file
        path: /path/to/spooldir
```

how do I find this `/path/to/spooldir` directory in my folder ? I'm confused

edit:
I am using this example here

[swiftmailer spool file path](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/swiftmailer-spooling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

```
#app/config/config.yml

swiftmailer:
    #...
    spool:
        type: file
        path: "%mailer_spool_path%"
```

Second:

```
#app/config/parameters.yml

parameters:
    #...
    mailer_spool_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/spool'
```

You will have access to this parameter by this way (In a command):

```
$spoolPath = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('mailer_spool_path');
```

Hope it will help you...